# Import simple_calendar gems CSS correctly on Rails 7 app generated with Bulma as CSS framework

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bulma, ruby-on-rails-7

I created a new Rails 7 app with `rails new Project -d=postgresql --css bulma` which sets up Bulma as the CSS framework. It creates `application.bulma.scss` where Bulma is imported with `@import 'bulma/bulma;`. I also set up the `simple_calendar` gem and render the month calendar inside one of my views. I put `@import 'simple_calendar';` inside `application.bulma.scss`. This doesn't do the trick for getting simple calendars default CSS to apply correctly to the calendars. I would really appreciate any insight on what I can do to get simple calendars default CSS to work.